# Clarity on the following summation rule

Tags: summation

Consider the following summation rule:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n c=nc$$
given that this is true, it implies that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}c=(n+1)c$$ and the question is, does this imply that the general case is $$\sum_{k=r}^nc=(n-r+1)c$$
I'm asking because I had to compute $$\sum_{k=20}^{100}(x+n)$$ and found that the answer was $81x+4860$ instead of $80x+4860$ as I expected it would be, and hence I made the inference that what I stated above is true. Is it true for all cases of $r,k$ and $c$?

Thank you.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n c_n = nc_n$ or $\sum_{k=1}^n c = nc$

Comment: yes if $ n \ge r$ otherwise it is debatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your second equation$\sum_{r=k}^n c = (r-k+1)c \tag{1}$ should be $\sum_{r=k}^n c = (n-k+1)c$.
Your last equation $\sum_{k=20}^{100}(x+n)$ should be $\sum_{k=20}^{100}(x+k) \tag{2}$. The result is $(100-20+1)(x) + \sum_{k=20}^{100} k $ = 81x+4860.
So your general summation is right.